# How does enemy respawning work in Lost Ruins?

Tags: lost-ruins

I've noticed that when I defeat an enemy they won't immediately respawn if I leave a room and come back, but most will eventually respawn if I come back later on. The respawn doesn't seem to be triggered by saving or warping.

What causes enemies to respawn in Lost Ruins?

Answer (score 1):

Respawning seems to be if the Heroine travels a certain number of rooms, and/or kills a certain number of enemies, or maybe zones.

I have a Hardcore save where I broke the first jar in the sewers, then immediately went back to the Garden of Genesis to save, took out its first Goblin, went back to get Smartphone #3, then upon returning to the sewer jar, it had respawned.